# HttpClient throws before attempting the request because of invalid authorization header

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10

So the problem I'm having is that the HttpClient keeps throwing an exception before it even attempts the request. I think I was able to narrow it down to the authorization header. Here's how I'm making the call:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    var authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;           

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString))
        return null;

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
    return obj;
}
```

Here, I've removed all headers except for the Auth header. If I remove that header, then the request will go through and I'll get a 401 response as expected without the token. If I changed the value of `token` to "ABC" then the request will go through but return an error from the server I'm talking to, as expected.

I've also tried adding the Authorization header by using `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", token);` and I end up with the same result: "Invalid HTTP headers."

Here is the content of the token without the "Bearer" scheme at the front:
[image]

Here's the thing. I realize that the format of the token probably doesn't meet some standard somewhere and that's why it's failing the validation before it sends off, but this is the only platform on which it has been a problem. This is infuriating.

Is there some way to bypass this behavior or some other client I can use in a windows 10 universal app?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing schema name "Bearer" when adding header without validation, see below how it should be:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer  " + token)
```